# Iterate over a dictionary by comprehension and get a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

How to iterate over a dictionary by dictionary comprehension to process it.

```
>>> mime_types={
    '.xbm': 'image/x-xbitmap',
    '.dwg': 'image/vnd.dwg',
    '.fst': 'image/vnd.fst',
    '.tif': 'image/tiff',
    '.gif': 'image/gif',
    '.ras': 'image/x-cmu-raster',
    '.pic': 'image/x-pict',
    '.fh':  'image/x-freehand',
    '.djvu':'image/vnd.djvu',
    '.ppm': 'image/x-portable-pixmap',
    '.fh4': 'image/x-freehand',
    '.cgm': 'image/cgm',
    '.xwd': 'image/x-xwindowdump',
    '.g3':  'image/g3fax',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.npx': 'image/vnd.net-fpx',
    '.rlc': 'image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-rlc',
    '.svgz':'image/svg+xml',
    '.mmr': 'image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-mmr',
    '.psd': 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
    '.oti': 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template',
    '.tiff':'image/tiff',
    '.wbmp':'image/vnd.wap.wbmp'
}

>>> {(key,val) for key, val in mime_types.items() if "image/tiff" == val}
```

This is returning result like this:

```
set([('.tiff', 'image/tiff'), ('.tif', 'image/tiff')])
```

But I'm expecting

```
('.tif', 'image/tiff')
```

How can I modify that result to get a dictionary like :

```
{'.tif': 'image/tiff'}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression:

```
{ value for bar in iterable }
```

is a [*set comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes).

In order to do a *dict comprehension*, you have to provide Python with a set of key-value pairs separated by `:`:

```
{ key: value for bar in iterable }
```

Answer (score 27):

Replace

```
{(key,val) for key, val in mime_types.items() if "image/tiff" == val}
```

with

```
{key: val for key, val in mime_types.items() if "image/tiff" == val}
```

Comment: just in case anyone else messes up, the `.items()` call on the dictionary is crucial.

Answer (score 6):

You can do [dictionary comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) as @Anubhav Chattoraj suggested.

Or pass a [generator expr](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) as an argument to function `dict`:

```
In [165]: dict((k, mimes[k]) for k in mimes if mimes[k] == "image/tiff")
Out[165]: {'.tif': 'image/tiff', '.tiff': 'image/tiff'}
```

**Don't** mix the two ways up..

Comment: It would have been better if you have avoided the `.items()`

Comment: @thefourtheye why? won't you get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`?

Comment: `dict((k, mimes[k]) for k in mimes if mimes[k] == image/tiff")` You ll be avoiding the intermediatate list generated by `.items()`

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm using python3 just now... anyway answer updated ;)

Comment: Actually this will work consistently in both Python2 and Python3. But, `items()` will return an iterator in Py3 but a list in Py2.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try something like this

>>> print {k : v for k, v in mime_types.iteritems()}

Another Simple Example

    >>> print {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}
    {0 : 'A', 1 : 'B', 2 : 'C', 3 : 'D'}
```